# File properties information in windows server 2008 (R2)

Tags: windows, file, properties, windows-xp, windows-server-2008

I know this is not a very common problem and very few people has concern with this but problem is still there, waiting for your feedback guys.

In windows XP, write click on file, select "Version" tab and you will have complete information about your file, for example "BuildType" and very important "Comments" to check that your application is Unicode or Non Unicode.  As you can see it this picture.

[image]

But in Windows Server 2008, if you right click and select "Details" you will get some information and most of them are just crap, for example windows copyright year, file description, language , original name. As you can see in this image,

[image]

My Question, is there any solution that you can activate these hidden information in system settings some where in windows 2008 server or any small application which i can install and can get my required information.

Problem arises because as we know that in coming year technically windows XP will be in grave.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately somebody has written a [3rd party extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118909/Windows-7-File-properties-Version-Tab-Shell-Extens) to bring back this functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Luke, I dont know why Microsoft removed the important information from the properties and why they do not realize that available info in properties is not much needed as compare to removed one.